# onClick - Outputting data onto new page or layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

This is probably quite basic but I've only needed a use for a feature like this now. I have a button that carries out a calculation when I click on it. The output is a number. I want to put that number into a TextView on a different layout. On it's own page basically.

I can already get what I want on the same page. Just do the whole

```
TextView.setText();
```

Can anyone help me put the data onto it's own page? So when I click the button it carries out the calculation AND opens this new page to put the answer on it?

I tried putting the TextView in a new layout file and calling it via a findViewById but that gave me a force close.

Any solutions? Thanks.

EDIT: Here's the code, I'm trying to display the time on another page. See below

```
public void getWakeUpTime (View v) {

    LocalTime localtime = new LocalTime();
    LocalTime dt = new LocalTime(localtime.getHourOfDay(), localtime.getMinuteOfHour());
    LocalTime twoHoursLater = dt.plusHours(2);

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
    Text1.setText("Time: " + twoHoursLater.toString(formatter));

}
```

Right now it displays on the same page under the TextView Text1.

Comment: @nOiAd Done. I'm using the Joda-time API to pull the time and add hours to it.

Comment: you need to send this data to the next activity on the click event of the button (I suppose that this button is to launch a new activity). You can use Shreya/Jay/Rajeshs answers to do that.

Comment: http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.in/2012/09/sending-data-from-one-activity-to-other.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass integer to next activity using this code:

```
String num;
Intent i = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
i.putExtra("value", num);
startActivity(i);
```

You can retrieve the data on next activity as shown below:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String num = i.getStringExtra("value");
textview.setText("Number is: "+num);
```

Comment: I've added the code I'm trying to send, it's already in a String. I'm using the Joda-time API to get it.

Comment: @RED_, So its straight forward. What's the problem now? If you need some help on this, you can refer to http://getablogger.blog , http://www.javasrilankansupport.com/2012/06/send-data-to-another-activity-simple.html posts, too.

Comment: Ah Ok if the same code can still work then they'll be no problem. I'm still implementing it, just telling everyone I posted the code incase that changes anything

Comment: @RED_, No it won't change anything else.. :) Ur prob is solved.

Comment: Thank you, I'll accept your answer. First to answer with code advice etc!

Comment: I too wrote the answer at the same time. My answer being lengthy although. I know ... haha.. but when I saw her answer. It was nice and well summarized. and well a good decision to accept her answer... :) have a great day brother. :)

Answer (score 2):

So brother, here you want is that you have calculated a value in 1st page and you want to show it on the 2nd page am I right?

For this brother you need to pass some data(i.e. Bundle) while calling the next activity.

Here's a similar Application that I built few months back. It passes the message created in one activity to another. Hope this works for you.

The following code is from the first activity where message is created and it is bundled and sent to the next activity.

```
    public void yourMethod(View view ){

        // Fetching the message to be sent to the next activity.
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        // Remember this constant(or any string you can give). to be used on other activity.
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);

        startActivity(intent);

}
```

And this is what I did on the onCreate Method of the Activity which was called by the previous Activity.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
   // save the passed message as string so that it can be displayed anywhere in this activity.
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
}
```

Hope My Program give you enough light to your solution. Hope that satisfies you.
Thanks brother.

Comment: I've added the code I'm trying to send. I'm using the Joda-time API to get the time and add hours to it.

Comment: that shall work for you. but be sure to convert those integers to string before showing any output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the data as an Extra. [Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) has all the information you need.